Android OpenGL alpha Blending Stuttering Issue
I am trying to develop a Virtual Production app in android.
The green screen should be removed and a 3d Object should be placed in that place.
I almost done the changes based on multiple opensource projects.
But the alpha region gets stuttering.
Camera Showing the green screen


My APP: (Green screen replaced with alpha and 3d object)


The marked one in the above is the 3d object. It is created in separate.
This is the one used for blending.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    glEnable(GLES30.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES30.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES30.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

I am a java developer and new to Android Programming. I am just joining multiple pieces of code  together. Any help would be appreciated.
Full Source here https://bitbucket.org/kannan3216/virtual_camera/src/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/camera2api/DirectVideo.java
I am expecting the clean result without any stuttering
